# No output when executing a command on Phing

Tags: phing

I have the following build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Example" default="test" description="Sample Description">
    <target name="test">
        <exec command="ls" dir="./" />
    </target>
</project>
```

However the Phing seems to run this command without outputting anything:

```
Buildfile: /path/to/build/file/build.xml

Example > test:


BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.2106 seconds
```

How can I fix this?

Note that the phpunit test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use argument

```
passthru="true"
```

More information at https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/ExecTask.html

Comment: Brilliant worked great thanks. The documentation did not seem to explain what that is very well unfortunately.